# Type Confusion in C++

Tags: c++, vtable

I am referring to this [link](https://bufferoverflows.net/type-confusion-vulnerabilities/).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Base {}; // Parent Class

class Execute: public Base {   // Child of Base Class
public:
    virtual void exec(const char *program) 
    {
        system(program);
    }
};

class Greeter: public Base {   // Child of Base Class
public:
    virtual void sayHi(const char *str) 
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

};


int main() {

    Base *b1 = new Greeter();
    Base *b2 = new Execute();
    Greeter *g;

    g = static_cast<Greeter*>(b1); // Safe Casting to the same type "Greeter"
    g->sayHi("Greeter says hi!"); // String passed to sayHi() function

    g = static_cast<Greeter*>(b2); // Unsafe Casting to sibling class "Execute"
    g->sayHi("/usr/bin/xcalc"); // String passed to exec() function 
                                    // which will turn into a command to execute calculator

    delete b1;
    delete b2;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is about the statements:

```
g = static_cast<Greeter*>(b2);
g->sayHi("/usr/bin/xcalc");
```

`b2` is an instance of type `Execute`. The b2 instance will have a vpointer to vtable containing entry for `exec()`. When the next statement calls `g->sayHi(..)`, how will the vtable be used to look up which function to call ?

Referring to [link](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/), it states that:

> the function name is used as index to the vtable to find the correct
> (most specific) routine to be executed

If the name of the function is used, then how is the name `sayHi` found in the vtable for type `Execute` ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you *know* that the second `g->sayHi` call is UB because of the `static_cast` before it? Then whatever happens in the unspecified implementation that you are using is an internal detail of that implementation, which you can lookup in its sources if available. Most likely, the code ends up using the `Execute` vtable with the index calculated for the `Greeter` vtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is mapped to an index in the vtable at compile time, so at run time the function call is just an array lookup.

The code in question results in Undefined Behavior, because a `b2` is not a `Greeter*`. (A `dynamic_cast` would return `nullptr`.) One possible outcome is that the vtable entry for `sayHi` will have the same index as the `exec` function in `Execute`, so while the source code looks like it will call `sayHi`, it will actually call `exec`. Or it could crash.

But anything can happen.